# problem when using function12 to convert figma to flutter code

Tags: flutter, user-interface, type-conversion, frameworks, figma

I just downloaded the Flutter code folder from function, I did use function12 to convert the Figma design to Flutter code, but I have this problem :

```
Error: 'AssetManifest' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/services/asset_manifest.dart' and 'package:google_fonts/src/asset_manifest.dart'.
google_fonts_base.dart:32
AssetManifest assetManifest = AssetManifest();
```

This is my code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:myapp/utils.dart';
import 'package:myapp/ui/wirefram-onboarding1.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      scrollBehavior: MyCustomScrollBehavior(),
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Text(
          'Hello',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried everything ChatGPT asked me to do, from specifying the import to checking the version but nothing seems to work, is this a recurring problem or is it just my code, has anyone had this problem, how did they fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Update the google_fonts version in pubspec.yaml to the [latest](https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).